# IntelliJ IDEA: Running a shell script as a Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way by which a shell script can be invoked from IntelliJ Run/Debug configurations?

Comment: **If you want to see such a feature in PyCharm please vote on [IDEA-112256 'Command Line' Run Configuration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112256) feature request.**

Answer (score 79):

I just found out that we can invoke a shell script with the help of **[BashSupport](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230?pr=phpStorm)** plugin.

Comment: Any ideia of how to debug it?

Comment: BashSupport plugin is deprecated after IDEA 2020.2, and now the paid [BashSupport Pro](https://www.bashsupport.com/pro/) is used. However, the -[Shell Script](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13122-shell-script)  plugin can still be used

Answer (score 69):

'Add External tool' in the 'Before Launch' does the trick.

Screenshot

[image: edit tool add shell script]

Comment: This worked well - thank you.

I used Program:
  `  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\rm.exe `
And Parameters: 
  `   -fr ~/.grails/.slcache/ `

As another example

Comment: Doesn't this still run one of the standard run/debug configurations *after* running this external script?  What if you wanted to only run your own external script?

Comment: To find the path to `sh` or `bash`, enter `which sh` or `which bash` in a shell.
You can use `$ProjectFileDir$` as the *Working directory*, which is a macro pointing to the project root directory. Other macros (e.g. for module specific directories) can be found under the *Insert macro...* button.

Comment: what if I need it after launch?

Answer (score 21):

## IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 update

New version of IntelliJ IDEA has **Shell Script Support** included. It means you can now create *Shell Script build* for your project.

`Edit Configurations` **>** `(+) Add New Configuration` **>** `Shell Script`

You can also build your project before executing your script by adding *Run Another Configuration* task. That's how it looks like: [Add Shell Build window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKkL8.jpg)

Comment: Alas, if a java debug configuration uses a shell script in "Run Another Configuration", then only the shell script is started. The debug session isn't.

Comment: @Auric there is an issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229741

Comment: Any idea how to keep the shell window open after execution? or even just to print the output to IntelliJs own console?

Answer (score 10):

Not sure about 11, but in 12 there's a part of Run/Debug Configuration that is called "Before Launch" and you can select your shell script in "Add External tool" option.

Comment: Thanks. I used to to run a shell script to concatenate JS files before launching my Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom shell script first.
[image: custom shell]
Then, add that to "Before Launch" in the next npm run.
[image: add before launch]