# Where to put executable shell scripts in Grails project

Tags: bash, grails, intellij-idea

Having a scenario in my current Grails project where need to add some independent executable to files at proper location. These files would not be used anywhere inside the Grails project but would be called from Bash shell to send some messages to Messaging queue (RabbitMQ for example).

What is the best place inside a Grails project to add these scripts.

Should add these to already existing script folder inside the Grails project structure.

Or should add these by directly creating a folder (say) in root as below

```
project>
     |grails-app
     |scripts
     |lib
     |target
     |web-app
     |**imeiscripts** > My scripts here
```

Also, is it possible to run these scripts from IntelliJ Idea with supplying arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put them anywhere you like.  a very common place for such files would be `/bin` in unix fashion.

for your second question: [IntelliJ IDEA: Running a shell script as a Run/Debug Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203498/intellij-idea-11-running-a-shell-script-as-a-run-debug-configuration)

Comment: /bin. is it the folder that i need to create in the project