# How to automate feature branch merge on to develop?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, automation, webstorm

Using WebStorm IDE and typical gitflow. 
Day by day I am do same operations after work on feature is finished:

1. Push feature branch to remote
2. Checkout branch develop
3. Pull develop updates from remote
4. Merge feature branch to develop
5. Stop in case of any merge-conflicts. Manually resolve conflicts.
6. Push develop to remote

Are there any plugins to automate this simple actions (except #5) by one button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One button": you would need to [record a macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) and bind a keyboard shortcut to said macro.

But that would not take into account the comment you need to enter when merging, or the potential conflict resolution.

You could also write a script, and declaring it as an [external tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105293/6309).
In that script, the merge step would stop if there is conflict.