# Try to access env variables in ubuntu /etc/profile with Java program

Tags: java, ubuntu, system, environment

I'm writing a program in which I have to get some env variables like JAVA_HOME with the IDE IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu.

I have set all my env variables in **/etc/profile** and **~/.bashrc**, but with code like `System.getenv()`, I cannot access the env that I have set since the code may only access variables set in /etc/environment.

So is there any way to find these variables in **/etc/profile** with Java program in the **Ubuntu** system?

My code sample:

```
public class EnvVarTest {[enter image description here][1]
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                    envName,
                    env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
SHELL=/bin/bash
OLDPWD=/home/lin/ideaIC-2020.1.4/idea-IC-201.8743.12/bin
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=root
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
SUDO_COMMAND=./idea.sh
SUDO_USER=lin
SUDO_GID=1000
DISPLAY=:0
MAIL=/var/mail/root
COLORTERM=truecolor
LOGNAME=root
SUDO_UID=1000
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
PWD=/home/lin/code/Test
HOME=/root
```

[etc-profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz8T0.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is presumably because IntelliJ runs the application in a non-login shell. One solution could be to source `/etc/profile` as part of the run configuration. Check out this [stack overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203498/intellij-idea-running-a-shell-script-as-a-run-debug-configuration).